# How can one learn the overall Sharepoint development ecosystem?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-foundation, learning

Since Sharepoint is such a huge platform with so many components and it can be used in so many different ways, I was wondering if there are good examples of sample projects which demonstrate how the whole Sharepoint platform works ?

I ask this because there seem to be a lot of ways ( or places ) to integrate custom code in the Sharepoint platform (Workflows, Farm Solutions, Web Parts, the new Apps, client side JS code etc.)

In fact some of those may even overlap and you can implement one requirement in several different ways in Sharepoint.

So what I am looking for is any resource explaining the whole model end to end and showing how it can be customized in each place or walking through a sample project that touches each aspect of Sharepoint development while explaining it.

P.S - I tried to do my research but haven't yet come across something that covers all aspects of Sharepoint. I am under the impression that it is hard to learn Sharepoint with books and other resources. It seems like years of first hand experience is the only way to really grasp it. (Unlike technologies like ASP.Net, MS SQL Server which have really good material to learn from)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in assuming that it's extremely hard to learn SharePoint in a theoretical sense. You learn SharePoint by getting thrown into the fire, and if you survive that experience you get thrown in again, and eventually you develop a proficiency.

I would advise not even trying to grasp the entire ecosystem all at once.  Pick collaboration or web content management, and get good at that.  You'll get much better ROI for that investment in the short run, and that knowledge will help ground your further studies as you expand your repertoire.  I've been a SharePoint consultant for six years, and worked on dozens of projects, and there are still aspects of the platform I have never touched - BI, for example.

Find a mentor or user group where you can get feedback on your work and ideas for new projects.  Find the trustworthy people in the online community and follow them. Stay connected with the advance of technology, it is accelerating rapidly and old patterns become obsolete quickly.

...finally, if I may promote a blog I wrote, here [is an article with advice for prospective SharePoint Devs](http://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/become-a-great-sharepoint-developer-in-10-easy-steps/)

Answer (score 1):

it is very much opened ended and i dont think you get all the pieces on one place.

SharePoint 2013 is a development platform for apps for SharePoint and farm solutions. Get acquainted with the capabilities and features of SharePoint 2013 to start your development.

[SharePoint 2013 development overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164084%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Learn about new features and functionality in SharePoint 2013, including the new Cloud App Model, development tools, platform enhancements, mobile apps, and more

[What’s new for developers in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163091%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Or I would recomend go through online training video i.e Plurarsight.
http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/understanding-sharepoint2013-development